# Detect off-route with graphhopper offline navigation

Tags: routes, navigation, openstreetmap, graphhopper

I'm developing an app with navigation system using graphhopper offline. 
I have a gpx route displayed correctly with map-matching and the goal is the user needs to follow this route. If the user needs to take other way for some circumstances the app must recalculate the route. The problem is I can't detect when the user is off-route to recalculate. I have gps location updates, instruction list, and gpx entries. Anyone can help?

Comment: If you have GPX data you could check whether the user is still on the track or has a distance > n meters from the closest track point.

Comment: Maybe you join the discussion at: https://discuss.graphhopper.com/t/when-do-i-need-to-re-route/1920

Comment: I posted on the graphhopper forum , @scai the problem is that a track not have constants point, you can have one point at 100 or 200 meters, or 20 meters, and you can deviate 50 meters and take a parallel way, it's very complicated I think